# How to get the result for this condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose, We have two tables:- **Branch** and **User**

**Branch:**

```
BranchCode  |  BranchName  | IsActive  |
----------------------------------------
   1        |    aaa       |   0       |
----------------------------------------
   2        |    bbb       |    1      |
---------------------------------------
   3        |    ccc       |     0     |
```

---

**User:**

```
UserId   |  Name  |
-------------------
  333     |  jjjj |
-------------------
  444      |  kkkk|
-------------------
```

We want to select result as

```
MemberId
--------
2 - 333
--------
2 - 444
-------
```

that means, we take the branchcode for those who has isactive = 1

I am facing problem to retrieve the resultset as the table has no relation, is there a way to get the result as expected?

Comment: What happens if two branches are active and one is inactive?

Comment: I'm not seeing any clear relation between the `Branch` and `User` tables.

Comment: There is no relation so what you want is not possible.

Comment: @simo - The answer below proves you wrong.  For the exact example dataset shown, a filter on `branch` and a `CROSS JOIN` on `user` is sufficient.  That works fine because only one row from `branch` is active.  What's unclear is what is meant to happen if two branches are active, or if that's even possible.

Comment: `declare @branchcode as int;
select top 1 @branchcode = branchcode from Branch where IsActive = 1;
select cast(@branchcode as varchar(100)) + '-' + Name from User`

Comment: @Nadeem - You should separate statements with `;` rather than with `,`.  You should also post an answer, not a code snippet in a comment.

Comment: @BlackCat - Your comment on the answer below says you're getting more rows than expected.  Please update your example data and expected results to demonstrate when that can happen and what you *want* to happen.  Knowing what *should* happen when there are multiple active branches is *extremely* important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CROSS JOIN` :

```
SELECT b.branchcode, u.UserId   
FROM brach b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT UserId FROM User u) u
WHERE b.IsActive = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(b.branchcode,' - ', u.UserId) MemberId FROM User u,brach b WHERE b.IsActive = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` as :

```
select concat(b.branchcode,'-',u.userid) as MemberId
  from branch b
 right outer join "user" u
    on b.isactive = 1;

MemberId
--------
2 - 333
2 - 444
```

*p.s. user is a reserved keyword in MSSQL, so I've used table `"user"` instead.*

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e9cc4/1)